# GUI testing with Jubula

Tags: user-interface, automated-tests, gui-testing, jubula

Can anyone help be about GUI testing in Jubula? I have a java GUI project, I created the jar file and put it into Jubula but after this step I couldnt do anything please help.

Answer (score 2):

It is a Rcp application or normal?If rcp please create the exe  and load it to jubula.
Below has some tutorial.

http://jmhofer.johoop.de/?p=163 Try to follow this